# WSO2 Cluster configuration deployment synchronization filter

Tags: wso2, load-balancing, wso2-esb

In a cluster configuration every modification is propagated from the manager to the worker. I have a scheduled task which have to run just on the manager.
What's the way i can stop the synchronization with the workers?

Answer (score 0):

Deployment synchronization does not happen as a schedule task .. once an artifact is uploaded to a manager node, manager sends a  cluster message to all other workers  specifying the repo is updated. Once the workers get the message it will update their repo's . So to if you want to disable worker's dep-sync then you need to disable DeploymentSynchronizer in carbon.xml(repository/conf/)

```
<DeploymentSynchronizer> 
  <Enabled>false</Enabled>
  ...
</DeploymentSynchronizer>
```

Please refer [this](http://docs.wso2.org/display/CLUSTER420/Introduction+to+Deployment+Synchronizer) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for answering... i already know the synchronization mechanism and how the deployment sync works by an svn server. The question was little different. I want to know if in a cluster there is the possibility to specify one or more resource that have not to be deployed on the worker nodes: i.e. i define a scheduled task on the manager but i don't want it (only the task... the other configurations have to follow the normal deployment) to be deployed on the worker nodes.